# how can i add end time for jquery timepicker

Tags: jquery

```
$(function() {
```

And i tried adding below code

```
 //    $('.timepicki').timepicki({
 //        min_hour_value:0,
 //        max_hour_value:23
 //    });
```

but its not working. can you anyone help me?

Comment: What's the purpose of using min/max hour when you set it to the full extents of the possible values?

Answer (score 2):

You would do something like this,

```
 $('#endTime').timepicker('option', 'minTime', new_min_time)
            });
```

OR you can try this one,

```
$('#startTime').timepicker({
            'minTime': '6:00am',
            'maxTime': '11:30pm',
                'onSelect': function() {

                $('#endTime').timepicker('option', 'minTime', $(this).val());                        
          }
        });
```